# What is a system tool?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, linux-kernel

I frequently come across the term system tool, so I wanted to understand the exact meaning of it in Linux.

Which of the following three explanations of a system tool in Linux is correct?

1. Is a system tool in Linux a tool that is installed for the system to use? (I don't know if the linux kernel calls tools such as `grep`, `ls` out of site of the terminal user.)
2. Or is a system tool a tool that is installed in the system via `dnf` only, for users of the system to use? This would make `jupyter-notebook` installed via `dnf` a system tool.
3. Is a system tool simply a commandline tool which means that it does not matter how the tool was installed i.e. a tool installed using `pip` or `dnf` is a system tool?

#### update:

To provide context in which the term is used, examples of usages of the term "system tool" are in this [thread](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/python-devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/3ZB2AZ77WN53E3XOB4AU7XKCJOJVHHHE/#BQDQD2YZNDGO6TDOOR5AURKIALMUW4JT)

Comment: Could you please point us to some of these usages of the term so that we may see the _context_ in which the term is used?

Comment: You tagged the question with [tag:linux-kernel]. Could you say something about the relationship between the question and the Linux kernel (it's not mentioned in the question).  Also, what makes you think that Linux systems have a specific definition of this term, as opposed to other Unix systems (or for that matter, other operating systems besides Unix)?

Comment: I don't thinks it has an official definition, but probably any tool found in LSB would qualify.

Comment: @Kusalananda , I have updated the question with examples of the term "system tool" which is used frequently in the linked fedora mailing list

Comment: @Jasen , can you expand on what you mean by LSB?

Comment: What is a system tool, depends on, what do we understand on "system" and what do we understand on "tool". In its most typical meaning, it is a command-line utility belonging to the very basic functionality of the OS.

Comment: @peterh so that means explanation number 1 is the correct explanation of the meaning of the term "system tool". Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia Because your question is held as "unclear". Held or closed questions can't be answered. But I already voted to reopen it, but it requires 5 votes and I am only 1. There is a little chance that yet another 4 vote arrives. Only people with at least 3000 reputation can vote to reopen a question. It takes some hundred answers to collect this rep.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia I said LSB (linux standard base)  but I think what I really meant was util-linux https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux

Comment: but that thread, could also mean distro-specific things like `aptitude` which is built on python.

Comment: A "system tool" is anything in /sbin 

https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#sbinSystemBinaries

Or

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: See man 8 https://linux.die.net/man/1/man

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no Linux-specific meaning for "system tool". A system tool is a program that is used to manage the system itself, instead of using it for "productive" use. A network connection manager or a disk formatter are system tools. A server software such as Apache or an office suite are not.

`grep` and `ls` are "utilities". They can be used as part of system tools or for productive use...

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I have updated the question with examples of usages of the term "system tool". From that link, particularly [this comment](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/python-devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/message/6GK4PNV3KBXTVD7QTDXU3DWAF2JU44TO/) I get the idea that a dnf installed jupyter notebook is considered a system tool

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia Just because some software developer thinks Jupyter is a system-tool does not make him correct. For that matter, what is a "system"? Is it a single computer? What about a VM with multiple containers that work together (in a "pod" by some nomenclatures) to provide a unified solution or application? You're underlying issue is you are trying to get concrete definitions for terms that are not precise fixed language. The word "hacker" is a classic example. Does "hacker" equate to malicious, criminal, or bad-intentioned people? The answer depends entirely on perspective and history.

Comment: @0xSheepdog , you make a good point. I guess because the quote was from one of the maintainers of fedora which is my system's distro, I took that fedora developer's word as gospel

Comment: And what a software developer, and system developer, and a system administrator consider to be a "system tool" can be wildly different. It's a matter of perspective.

Comment: I see, there is no standardized meaning of the term "system tool"

Comment: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#sbinSystemBinaries

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/man